# Form tag does not get added in Chrome and Opera

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog, forms

I have a button on my form. When I click that button I first ajaxpost to a webpage on the server, take inner html of the specified div and finally append that html to another div that will present a jqueryui dialog. Here's the code:

```
$('#window').html(content).
dialog({
    title: title,
    show: 'drop',
    hide: 'drop',
    width: 400,
    buttons: buttons,
    position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window }
}
);
```

And here's the inner html of the div on the posted page:

```
  <div id="cardOrder" class="cardOrder-div">
        <form runat="server" id="frmAjax" >
        <table class="cardOrder-tbl">
        ......
        </form>
  </div>
```

I have a problem with Chrome and Opera. When I click the button for the first time and show the jqueryui dialog with the above html content, the "form" tag is missing. But the next times when I present the dialog the form tag gets added. And if there's no form tag I cannot submit. Firefox and IE lack this problem. The form tag gets added right from the first dialog show.

EDIT: When I debug the code to see if the html content returned from the ajax response contains the form tag I can see it there. But when the content is added to the div it somehow disappears.

Comment: Do you have any live version of it ?

Comment: If you mean something like JSFiddle then I think it's not possible to to the post to the server

Comment: Is `#window` already within a form tag?

Comment: Yes, it's a child of my masterpage.

Comment: I'm glad you solved this, yet upset that I didn't check back for your answer to my question. Kinda missed some rep there, but more importantly you have solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by default the jquery dialog box gets added to the end of the `body` tag, and therefore, any controls you have in the dialog box are not part of the form, and will not get posted you might need to add something like this

```
$('#DIALOGID').dialog({
        open:function(event, ui){
            $(this).parent().appendTo('form');
        }
    });
    $('#DIALOGID').dialog('open');
```

this will append the dialog HTML to the end of the form tag, and controls within the dialog can then be accessed in code behind,

Also, I don't believe you can have more than 1 Form tag within a page.

**Unless this answer is completely unhelpful**

Comment: I've tried your solution before but unfortunately appending to the form did not solve the problem. However I've found another way which works on all browsers. Instead of using the predefined "window" div, I create the div on the fly and the problem goes away. So instead of writing $('window').dialog() I say $('<div id="window">').dialog(). Even assigning an id is not necessary here but I just add it for clarity. And btw, when I inspect the page source I see two form tags there. I think the limitation is that a form cannot be inside another form.

Comment: no problems, I've never tried nested forms, so didn't know about that limitation